# Computation of first étale cohomology group on a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

I just finished my first time learning étale cohomology, and now would like to compute some simple examples, here is one :

> Let $k=\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, and let $X$ be the curve $\text{Spec}\,k[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^2(X-1))\subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^2$, what is the first étale cohomology group $H^1_{ét}(X,\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_X)$ of the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_X$ on $X$ ?

Here is what I try to do. Let $f:\mathbb{A}_k^1\rightarrow X$ be the normalization morphism, then as $f$ is finite, we have $R^qf_*\mathcal{F}=0$ for every étale sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $\mathbb{A}_k^1$ and $q\geq 1$, hence $H^1_{ét}(\mathbb{A}_k^1,\mathcal{F})=H^1_{ét}(X,f_*\mathcal{F})$. So if there's a $\mathcal{F}$ with $f_*\mathcal{F}=\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_X$ we will be happy. My first thought was to take $\mathcal{F}=\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_{\mathbb{A}_k^1}$, but I realized that $f$ corresponds to the map
$$f:\mathbb{A}_k^1\rightarrow X,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,t\mapsto (t^2+1,t(t^2+1))$$
who is one-to-one except that the two points $t=\pm 1$ maps to $(0,0)$, so
$$(f_*\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_{\mathbb{A}_k^1})_{\overline{(0,0)}}=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z},$$
that is, this choice doesn't work.

Now I don't know how to continue. I would be grateful to anyone answering this question, or, giving any hint.

Comment: I know basically nothing about étale cohomology, but I assume there is a projection formula available. So what happens if you pull back $\underline{\mathbb Z}_X$ to the affine line? Can you go from there somehow?

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you for your comment ! Indeed I find a such formula in Fu Lei's book, it seems much complicated then in the usual Zariski setting, it will take me time to learn these stuff (btw I have the impression that this allows only to compute cohomology groups on torsion sheaves, like $\underline{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}_X$).

Finally we will arrive at something like $\mathcal{E}\otimes f_!\mathcal{F}\simeq f_!(f^*\mathcal{E}\otimes \mathcal{F})$ on $X_{ét}$. Could you tell me how to transfer this to things on $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ ?

Comment: (honestly I don't even know how to play with the projection formula in the Zariski, or other topological settings)

Comment: Like I said, I know so little about this stuff. You'll probably want to talk with someone who knows étale cohomology properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you aware of the fact that $H^1_{et}(X,\underline{\mathbb{Z}})$ is not a 'good group' to consider? For example, if $X$ is normal then it's zero since it's $\mathrm{Hom}_\text{cont}(\pi_1^{et}(X),\mathbb{Z}))$, and since $\pi_1^{et}(X)$ is profinite.

For your example you can see the proof of Angelo Vistoli [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/84417/38867)--it's essentially the same technique you were trying to apply. Perhaps the only non-obvious points in his explanation are why $H^1_{et}(X,\pi_\ast \underline{\mathbb{Z}}))$ and $H^1_{et}(X,i_\ast\underline{\mathbb{Z}})$ are trivial. But, since $\pi$ and $i$ are finite morphisms, they're acyclic for the etale topology, and so agree with $H^1_{et}(\mathbb{A}^1,\underline{\mathbb{Z}})$ and $H^1_{et}(\mathrm{pt},\underline{\mathbb{Z}})$ respectively. But, since $\mathbb{A}^1$ and $\mathrm{pt}$ are normal, I already explained why these are zero.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I am an absolute beginner and don't know which "good groups" to consider. Do you know where to find some concrete computations of etale cohomology ? I feel I don't know much more than $H^{\dot}_{et}(\text{Spec} K,\mathcal{F})$, $H^{\dot}_{et}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$, or $H^{\dot}_{et}(X,\underline{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}})$..

Comment: @wormsgo I mean, the real question is that besides things like $\underline{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\mathbb{G}_m$, what are the other natural sheaves which occur on general $X$? This may not be precisely what you're looking for, but on my blog (DISCLAIMER: THIS IS MY BLOG--SO OBVIOUSLY BIASED) there are some computations that may be of interest to you. I'll list them in the next comment.

Comment: https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/a-computation-a-day-compactly-supported-cohomology/
--------------------------------------------------
https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/a-computation-a-day-a-harder-pullback-pushforward/
-------------------------------
https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2016/09/19/a-computation-a-day-a-pullback-pushforward/
-------------------------------
https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2015/07/20/a-computation-a-day-the-brauer-group-of-a-number-ring/

Comment: While this is also of the type you mentioned, you might perhaps find the methods discussed in the following 3 blog posts of mine interesting:
-------------------
https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2019/11/27/punctured-disks-and-punctured-curves-and-cohomology-oh-my-part-i-the-proper-curve-case/
------------------
https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2019/11/27/punctured-disks-and-punctured-curves-and-cohomology-oh-my-part-ii-cohomology-with-supports/
-------------------
https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2019/11/27/punctured-disks-and-punctured-curves-and-cohomology-oh-my-part-ii-the-affine-curve-case/

Comment: Wow thank you for these examples, I will have a look at them. For example does it make sense to compute something like $H^{\cdot}_{et}(\text{Spec} K[X,Y,Z]/(X^5+Y^5+Z^5),\mathcal{F})$ for $\mathcal{F}$ a nice sheaf other than $\underline{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}$ or $\mathbb{G}_m$ ? Or things like $H^{\cdot}_{et}(X,h_Y)$ where $h_Y$ is the etale sheaf represented by another scheme $Y$ ?
By "make sense" I want to say do they tell new things about $X$ that $H^{\cdot}_{et}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$ or $H^{\cdot}_{et}(X,\underline{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}})$ are unable to ?

Comment: @wormsgo I mean, $H^i_{et}(X,h_Y)$ doesn't make sense for $i>0$ unless $Y$ is an $X$-group scheme, it doesn't make sense for $i>1$ unless $Y$ is a commutative $X$-group scheme (ignoring the gerbe interpretation of $H^2$ by Giraud). And, sure, if $\mathcal{F}$ is an abelian sheaf on $\mathrm{Spec}(k[x,y,z]/(X^5+Y^5+Z^5))$ then it makes sense to compute the etale cohomology, but what $F$ are you interested in? Do you know the general yoga of torsors? Do you know what $H^1_{et}(X,\mu_n)$ looks like? If you're interested in arithmetic examples, you may want to look at things like

Comment: the calculation of the Brauer groups of certain spaces (which is $H^2_{et}$) for the usage in the Brauer--Manin obstruction to rational points (e.g. see the book 'Rational points on Varieties' by Bjorn Poonen), or maybe you're interested in understanding the torsion of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ that highly involves bounding the fppf cohomology of certain finite flat group schemes on $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ (e.g. see Mazur's paper on the Eisenstein ideal). The list goes on. You just need to find an $\mathcal{F}$ that means something to you.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about the general yoga of torsors, and $H^1_{et}(X,\mu_n)\simeq \text{Pic}(X)[n](k)$ on an algebraic closed field $k$, where $n\not\mid \text{char} k$. I will read the book and the paper you mentioned. I am interested in arithmetic examples, do you think Mazur's paper is a good starting point to learn how to manipulates all these stuff ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111753/discussion-between-alex-youcis-and-wormsgo).